# How do I count number of characters after dot

Tags: c#

```
string num ="123.12400";
```

I need to get the number of characters after the '.'

Comment: There are five characters after the dot. You are welcome.

Comment: I count seven... excluding the newline.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
num.Length - num.IndexOf(".")-1;
```

Comment: And if you have input like "800.555.1212", and you need the length of "1212", use `num.LastIndexOf`

Answer (score 2):

```
num.SubString(num.IndexOf(".") + 1).Length;
```

Will work, as long as there is always some chars after the '.'

Comment: No need to instantiate a new string and allocate it in memory to calculate the length.

Comment: True, it's not as efficient as @Grzenio's, it's just another alternative you could use

Comment: ...@Grenzio's example using + 1 would become 
num.Length -(num.IndexOf(".") + 1);

Comment: @MikeTWebb - Ok I see, I thought that was how he was doing it but you're right, I was just reading it wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] s = num.split('.');
int count = s[1].Length;
```

Comment: (similar to w69rdy) No need to instantiate a new string array to calculate the length

Comment: what if there is no '.'  or the '.' is at the beginning or end of the string? Then, s[1] = null and s[1].length will cause an exception.  I would not use this method, unless you know the '.' will exist and it will be somewhere in the middle

Answer (score 1):

This should be the most readable form.

```
num.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Skip(1).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 12345.67;
var after_dot = (a.toString().split(".")[1]).length;
var before_dot= (a.toString().split(".")[0]).length;
```

--
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881319/is-there-ay-js-function-to-find-value-before-and-after-decimal-point))