# Is there ay JS function to find value before and after decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a decimal number using JavaScript.
Am just using `NaN`

var a = 12345.67
Is there any javascript function to get the  count or the value itself before and after decimal point .

```
before()  should return 1234
after() should return 67
```

Please dont suggest a substring!

Comment: a simple question . different people different answers . this is the success of SO . great :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var a = 12345.67;

alert(a.toString().split(".")[0]); ///before
alert(a.toString().split(".")[1]); ///after
```

Here is a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qWtSc/

---

**zzzzBov's suggestion is this**

```
Number.prototype.before = function () {
  var value = parseInt(this.toString().split(".")[0], 10);//before
  return value ? value : 0;
}

Number.prototype.after = function () {
  var value = parseInt(this.toString().split(".")[1], 10);//after
  return value ? value : 0;
}
```

Usage

```
alert(a.before()); ///before
alert(a.after()); ///after
```

Comment: Thanks . but i thought there will be some numeric function. this will work anyway but this string function if you fin any numeric function please suggest

Comment: @user987880, you could just extend `Number.prototype` to add the necessary functions.

Comment: Those functions fail for large numbers, i.e. when scientific notation is used instead.

Comment: `100.10`   after decimal point returns `1`,
`100.0000` after decimal point returns `NaN`,
Maybe this is the expected behaviour, it surprised me though.

Answer (score 21):

`before` is easy.  It's just a round down operation.

```
var before = function(n) {
  return Math.floor(n);
};
```

`after` is harder without string processing.  I mean how would you handle `after(Math.PI)`? You can't hold a integer with an infinite number of digits after all.

But with some string processing it's easy, just know it won't be exact due to the wonders of floating point math.

```
var after = function(n) {
  var fraction = n.toString().split('.')[1];
  return parseInt(fraction, 10);
};
```

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation ! so Just Thanks for now :-)

Comment: If you want the decimal after - (i.e. 1.123 = 0.123) you can just do `n - Math.floor(n)`

Comment: Because question was about 'after' as an integer, to get it would be easy like this then: (n - Math.floor(n))*100

Answer (score 2):

```
var decimalPlaces = 2;    
var num = 12345.673
var roundedDecimal = num.toFixed(decimalPlaces);

var intPart = Math.floor(roundedDecimal);
var fracPart = parseInt((roundedDecimal - intPart), 10);

//or

var fractPart = (roundedDecimal - intPart) * Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
```

Comment: They wanted the fracPart to be 67, not .67.

Comment: @user987880 Added some code -approached from a different angle :)

Answer (score 2):

Playing off of other answers... and you wanted a 'numeric' version.. still easiest to convert it to a string and work off the split function...

```
function getNatural(num) {
    return parseFloat(num.toString().split(".")[0]);
}
function getDecimal(num) {
    return parseFloat(num.toString().split(".")[1]);
}
var a = 12345.67;

alert(getNatural(a)); ///before
alert(getDecimal(a)); ///after
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/qWtSc/1/

Answer (score 1):

To find the count/length of characters after dot:

```
var a = 12345.67;
var after_dot = (a.toString().split(".")[1]).length;
var before_dot= (a.toString().split(".")[0]).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to get the factional part in a reliable way using math functions, because pretty odd roundings often occur, depending on the Javascript engine used.
The best thing to do is to convert it to a string, and then checking if the results is in decimal or scientific notation.

```
Number.prototype.after = function() {
    var string = this.toString();
    var epos = string.indexOf("e");
    if (epos === -1) { // Decimal notation
        var i = string.indexOf(".");
        return i === -1 ? "" : n.substring(i + 1);
    }
    // Scientific notation
    var exp = string.substring(epos + 1) - 0; // this is actually faster
                                              // than parseInt in many browsers
    var mantix = n.string.substring(0, epos).replace(".", "");
    if (exp >= -1) return mantix.substring(exp + 1);
    for (; exp < -1; exp++) mantix = "0" + mantix;
    return mantix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your digits after decimal point are fixed, then this solution works without converting to string.

This example shows a solution for 2 digits after decimal.

Before decimal:

```
   const wholeNum = Math.floor(num);
```

After decimal:

```
   let decimal = (num - wholeNum) * 100
```